# Execute a function without blocking the application android?

Tags: android, multithreading

How to call and execute a function without blocking the application android (this is the location function).

I know I must use the thread but I do not know how, I hope to have a code ready.

Comment: Have a read through the [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2009/05/painless-threading.html) article on the Android Dev site. It's pretty old (in Android terms), but still offers some valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to run code on a separate (non-UI) Thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //do stuff here
        }
    }).start();
```

This creates a new Thread (and corresponding Runnable which contains the code to be run inside its `run()` method ) and starts it -- calling the code in the Runnable.

Alternatively, you could look into `AsyncTask` ([more info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) which avoids using Threads directly.